# Rake commands not working in Elastic Beanstalk production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am having a tough problem with my Elastic Beanstalk environment.  Any Rake commands respond with Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!.  rake db:migrate, even a simple command like rake:stats, responds the same way.  On my local machine, everything works as expected.
The worst aspect of this is that I can't run migrations, whether manually or from within an .ebextension file. I'm stuck.  Can anybody help?

Comment: What is your production server?

Comment: It's an EC2 t2.micro, 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.2 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)

Comment: Have installed rails properly?

Comment: Oh gosh, I think I lucked into the answer.  The app has been running for over a year--but within the last week, I upgraded from Rails 4 to Rails 5.  Left over was a piece of code within lib/tasks, that had within it require "rake/testtask"  and require "rake/testtask"  .  Once I commented out that piece of code, and redeployed, it worked .

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded the app from Rails 4 to Rails 5.  A piece of code under lib/tasks/test_services.rake contained this:

```
require "rake/testtask"
require 'rails/test_help'
namespace :test do
#  desc 'Test tests/services/* code'
  Rails::TestTask.new(services: 'test:prepare') do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/services/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end 
Rake::Task['test:run'].enhance ['test:services']
```

I don't know for sure, but I'm thinking that one of those require statements was causing rake to "try" to run tests, even for commands such as rake stats. when I commented out every line, rake began functioning correctly.